# Copy selected range in a sheet to other place in a same sheet with Google Scripteditor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, selected

In Google Spreadsheets i try to copy some selected cells to another place in the sheet with Google Scripteditor.
I have this code, but it doesn't work:

```
function kopieerDag() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(sheet);
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();
  // var values = selection.getValues();
  Logger.log(selection);
  selection.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 1), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

any ideas? thx for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of error in your script is that `getSelection()` is not directly returned the range object. Please use `getActiveRange()` for `getSelection()`. So can you try this modification?

#### From :

```
var selection = sheet.getSelection();
```

#### To :

```
var selection = sheet.getSelection().getActiveRange();
```

#### References :

- [getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSelection())

Comment: @Brecht Parmentier Thank you for your response.